# Javascript cache Symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, caching

I need to get datas in AJAX in my Symphony 2.8 project. So, i did the script, and registered.

I use Mac and Vagrant.

It correctly set up the first time the browser loads the page, but when i do some modifications (and reload the page), the script in the browser is corrupted.

I mean :

```
console.log(1);
```

will become

```
console.log(1);���������
```

instead of

```
alert(1);
alert(2);
```

or become

```
conso
```

instead of

```
var i;
```

I clear cache from browser everytime, and do hard reload (shift + cmd + r).

If I change the script name it works, but i can't change to a name that already existed or else it turns to the same problem.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem : disabled sendfile in nginx conf.